# how insert in mysql all href tags after dom parsing?

Tags: php, foreach

I'm stuck with a `foreach loop with which I want to import into a database including all tags/href after DOM parsing. This is my loop:

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
{       
    $sql1="INSERT INTO page (site_id,url) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$element->href')";  
}
```

Here's one that works fine:

```
$j=1;
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
{       
    echo $j++ . ') HREF: ' . $element->href . ' ' . '<br>';         
}
```

How can I make the first loop store all href tags and not only the last?

Comment: Did you forget to execute your query?

Comment: finaly i found a solution    
    

$k=0;
    foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
  $sql1 = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO page (site_id,url) VALUES ('$site_id','$element->href')");
  $k++;   
 }
 echo  $k ."  records added in table page". '<br>';
      

this works fine

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you loop through, resetting `$sql1` every time, and then I presume you execute the last query after the loop. What you should really be doing is to build a compound `INSERT` statement inside your loop, and execute that at the end. Doing multiple `INSERT`s in a loop is bad practice, and you can easily insert multiple rows with one query.

Something like...

```
$values .= sprintf('(%s), ', $element->href);
```

Of course, you'll need to remove the trailing comma. Something like...

```
$values = substr ($values, 0, strlen($values)-1);
```

And then...

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO page (url) VALUES ($values)";
```

Also, I don't know why you need to use `LAST_INSERT_ID`. You probably want to create an `AUTOINCREMENT` column, and just let MySQL do the work. If you explain what you're trying to do with `LAST_INSERT_ID` I can offer better advice.

It also goes without saying that you should be using either PDO or MySQLi prepared statements. PHP's MySQL functions are deprecated, insecure, and will be removed in a future version.

Comment: i tried this    <code>$sql1 = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO page (site_id,url) VALUES ('LAST_INSERT_ID()','$element->href')"); </code>   and worked ,but the LAST_INSERT_ID() isn't the same.                                      I have two tables SITE(id,url) and PAGE(id,site_id,url)  i used LAST_INSERT_ID to take the site_id and it helped me until now. what else i can use like  LAST_INSERT_ID ?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$sql = array();
    foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
{       
     $sql[] = "INSERT INTO page (site_id,url) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$element->href')"; 
}
```

Just use and array to store all the queries so you can execute them later by using a foreach loop, or just do the database lookup directly in the foreach loop you provided